# Stored Procedure to display values from sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, winforms

I am developing a windows application in vb.net. I have a requirement to retrieve values from a table based on certain criteria. My sql server table is as below.

### tbl ACCOUNT_DETAIL

[image]

I have a textbox in my windows form for displaying the corresponding GL_Account. The user will pass the **paidto** value to the back end and the procedure must return the corresponding **GL_Account**. But there is one more criteria : **while retrieving the GL_Account from the database, we need to check for wholefamily. If the WholeFamily is 1 then all the Accounts(*should be fetched from another table*) which starts with the GL_Account should be retrieved. Else only the GL_Account from "this" table needs to be sent.** The table which contains the entire account information is below

### tbl ACCOUNT_MASTER.

[image]

I have shown only a part of the data from the table here.

I have created a Cursor to fetch values from the Account_Detail table. But after fetching values i need to check for WholeFamily and based on the bit i need to pass values to the front end.

@PaidTo(int) is the SP Parameter that is passed from the frontend.

DECLARE @GLAccount VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @AccountName VARCHAR(MAX)

```
    DECLARE PV_CURSOR CURSOR
    FOR
        SELECT  GL_Account,WholeFamily 
        FROM    ACCOUNT_DETAIL
        WHERE PaidTo=@PaidTO

        OPEN PV_CURSOR
        FETCH NEXT FROM PV_CURSOR
        INTO @GLAccount,@AccountName
```

Now I am stuck as to how to proceed further. Sorry for my ignorance.

Please help me.

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Please post some code, what have you tried, what is the problem and such.

Comment: So the actual question is about *"How to write a sql cursor"*?? See [SQL Server Cursor Example](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/)

Comment: I am not sure if i need to use cursor for this.

Comment: What i wanted is if Wholefamily is 1 , Then all the account numbers which start with the GL_Account should be picked from the ACCOUNT_MASTER table. i.e Suppose if paidto is 4, then i need to display 5,500001,501,50101,1,101,1001,..else if paidto is 1, then i need to display only 201302

Answer (score 0):

I would not use a cursor in such a scenario...

If I understand what you are suggesting correctly, incase Whole_family is 1 then you need to pull all info from the other table in the same result set. The below query can have multiple rows for every GL_Account based on your entries in the Account_master.

```
SELECT PAIDTO
    , GL_ACCOUNT
    , WHOLEFAMILY
    , ACCOUNTNUMBER
    , ENGLISHNAME
FROM ACCOUNT_DETAIL
LEFT JOIN ACCOUNT_MASTER
    ON CASE 
            WHEN WHOLEFAMILY = 1
                THEN ACCOUNT_DETAIL.GL_ACCOUNT
            ELSE NULL
            END = ACCOUNT_MASTER.ACCOUNTNUMBER
```

Comment: What i wanted is if Wholefamily is 1 , Then all the account numbers which start with the GL_Account should be picked from the ACCOUNT_MASTER table. i.e Suppose if paidto is 4, then i need to display 5,500001,501,50101,1,101,1001,..else if paidto is 1, then i need to display only 201302

Comment: Subquery returned more than 1 value when i select PaidTo=1. If PaidTo=4 or 3 then its working fine.